# Proof that the product of a positive semidefinite matrix and an orthogonal matrix could be an arbitrary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A$ be an arbitrary invertible $n\times n$ matrix.
>
> Prove that there exist a positive semidefinite matrix $R$ and an orthogonal matrix $B$ such that $A = BR$.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Positive semidefinite implies symmetric? (It is usually taken to do so).

Answer (score 2):

This is called the polar decomposition for the matrices.

Given $A$, let $R = \sqrt{A^* A}$ and $B = AR^{-1}$. Then you can check that $B$ is orthogonal and you have your required decomposition.

Since $A^*A$ is positive semidefinite, it has a positive semidefinite square root. If your matrix $A$ is invertible, this decomposition is unique.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but how can i prove that B is orthogonal?

Comment: Just compute $B^{T}B$ and $BB^{T}$. Remember that $A^{*} = A^{T}$ in case of real matrices.